# How do you test that a function throws an exception?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function below and want to write a unittest to check if my code catches ConnectionError using mock library

```
def get_foo():
    try:
        return requests.get("http://www.bongani.com")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Error")
```

What I have:

```
import unittest
import mock


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('requests.get')
    def test_foo(self, mock_requests_get):
        mock_requests_get.side_effect = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()
        with self.assertRaises(requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
            get_foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305 , in patched
  return func(*args, **keywargs)
File "<ipython-input-24-15266e4f708a>", , in test_foo
  get_foo()
AssertionError: ConnectionError not raised
```

I want to mock the `return requests.get("http://www.bongani.com")` line so that it raises an exception when called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is not bubbled up (i.e. it is suppressed) because you caught it and then you did not re-raise it. In turn, your unit tests will fail because you are testing that your function raises that exception while it is suppressing it.

You either change the function or the unit test of the function depending on which behavior is desired.

Assuming the tests are right then your function need to re-raise the exception like this:

```
def get_foo():
    try:
        return requests.get("http://www.bongani.com")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Error")
        raise  # <---------------- add this line
```

Another scenario, the function is right and the tests are wrong. You fix your tests to look like this:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('requests.get')
    def test_foo(self, mock_requests_get):
        mock_requests_get.side_effect = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()
        self.assertIsNone(get_foo())  # <----- no more assertRaises
```

Comment: I went with scenario 2. Thanks for making me see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you patch the correct path

```
@mock.patch('path.to.get_foo.requests.get')
```

You don't want to instantiate the exception.

```
mock_requests_get.side_effect = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
```

Comment: Still getting the same results.